# Issue with the configuration of HTTPS WCF hosted on Azure

Tags: .net, asp.net, azure, cloud

I using a third party secure WCF service hosted on Azure . I am trying to create my own secure HTTPS service but I am not able to use it. I am able to host it on Azure however when I use it in a client application I got following error

"There was no endpoint listening at https://xxxx.cloudapp.net/AsycServ/ AsycServCallback .svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action"

I compared the WSDL file of the third party service with the one I hosted. I found following difference

wsdl:Service section of third party service

```
- <wsdl:service name="SubsManagement"><br/>
- <wsdl:port name="WSHttpBinding_IxxxManagement" binding="tns:WSHttpBinding_IxxxManagement"><br/>
 <soap12:address location="https://xxx.yyy.com/Syndication/SubscriptionManagement.svc" /> <br/>
- <wsa10:EndpointReference><br/>
 <wsa10:Address>https://xxx.yyy.com/Syndication/SubsMgmt.svc</wsa10:Address> <br/>
- <Identity xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2006/02/addressingidentity"><br/>
 <Dns>xxx.yyy.com</Dns><strong> <br/>
</strong>
 </Identity><br/>
 </wsa10:EndpointReference><br/>
 </wsdl:port><br/>
 </wsdl:service>
```

wsdl:service section of my service

```
- <wsdl:service name="AsycServCallback">
- <wsdl:port name="WSHttpBinding_IxxxCallback" binding="tns:WSHttpBinding_IxxxCallback">
 <soap12:address location="http://ippbposstage.cloudapp.net:81/MOSI/MOSICallback.svc" /> 
- <wsa10:EndpointReference>
 <wsa10:Address>http://xxx.cloudapp.net:81/test/AsycServCallback.svc</wsa10:Address> 
- <Identity xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2006/02/addressingidentity">
 <Dns>localhost</Dns> 
 </Identity>
 </wsa10:EndpointReference>
 </wsdl:port>
 </wsdl:service>
```

I found two differences

1. Address location of the third party service does not contains port name while my service is pointing to port 81 , however t is hosted on HTTPS. So I was expecting https : in address.
2. My WSDL shows  = localhost while for third party service it is =xxx.yyy.com .

Am i missing anything in configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish. You should be able to deploy a simple WCF service on Azure. You have to make sure that you set the port in the service definition. Normally if you want to go https, it is easiest to leave it on port 443. Also, you need to make sure you deploy the cert to Azure that you are using for https.

If your sample is deployed on port 81, it looks like you need to add the port to your call. It would be https://xxxx.cloudapp.net:81/AsycServ/AsycServCallback.

Hope that helps.